# Select Elements To List Linq

Tags: c#, xml, linq

Trying to extract list of "Queue" Elements into a new list of Queue objects. I have the following xml:

```
<MSMQData>
 <Queues>
  <Queue env="LOCAL" server="WORK150">FormatName:DIRECT=OS:WKSTN150\private$\localqueue1</Queue>
  <Queue env="TEST" server="TEST01">FormatName:DIRECT=OS:dev-test01\private$\testqueue</Queue>
  <Queue env="PROD" server="empty"></Queue>
  <Queue env="PROD" server="empty"></Queue>
 </Queues>
</MSMQData>
```

Here's my code that obviously does not bring me back a list of Queue Elements that I'm trying to retrieve.  What am I missing here?

```
var queues = (from col in xmlMSMQLoad.Descendants("Queues")
              select col)
             .Select(c => new Queue
             {
                 Environment = c.Element("Queue").Attribute("env").Value,
                 Server = c.Element("Queue").Attribute("server").Value,
                 QueueName = c.Element("Queue").Value
             })
             .ToList();
```

By the way I do have a class called `Queue` with these properties in it.

Comment: Your code certainly looks like queues is a List<Queue>(). What are you expecting and what are your actual results?

Comment: I'm getting only the first "Queue" element. Trying to get all "Queue" elements back.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your current approach finds "Queues" then only selects the first "Queue" item. It doesn't grab all of them. What you want to do is use `Descendants("Queue")` or first select the "Queues" element and then its "Queue" elements.

Use this query instead:

```
var queues = (from c in xml.Element("Queues").Elements("Queue")
             select new Queue
             {
                 Environment = c.Attribute("env").Value,
                 Server = c.Attribute("server").Value,
                 QueueName = c.Value
             }).ToList();
```

Comment: Awesome worked like a charm! Thanks Ahmad and to all who commented!

Answer (score 1):

In `c.Element("Queue")`:

`c` is the `"Queues"` element, and `c.Element("Queue")` is the **first** `"Queue"` element. Therefore you only get the first one.

Answer (score 1):

```
var queues = doc
        .Descendants("Queue")
        .Select(x => new Queue
            {
                Env = x.Attribute("env").Value,
                Server = x.Attribute("server").Value,
                QueueName = x.Value
            })
        .ToList();
```

You're linq was a little messed up. By selecting the "Queue" descendants, your iterating over them rather than always selecting the first "Queue" node in your select. I've never liked the long form of linq, and have never had any luck combining the chained and long forms. Hope this helps!